# How to sort a view easily

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework3, zend-view

I'd like to sort my tablebased view in Zend 3.

Here is part of my viewscript:

```
<table class="table">
<tr>
    <th>id</th>
    <th>cccid</th>
    <th>gesch id</th>
    <th><a href="<?= $this->url('mandant',array('query' => array('sort' => 'desc'))); ?>">Name</a> </th>
    <th>langname</th>
    <th>&nbsp;</th>
</tr>


<?php 

foreach ($mandants as $mandant) : 
    //  $unit=$units->fetchAllP($project->ProjectID);
//var_dump(get_object_vars($project));?>
     <tr>
         <td><?= $this->escapeHtml($mandant->id)?></td>
         <td><?= $this->escapeHtml($mandant->cccid) ?></td>
         <td><?= $this->escapeHtml($mandant->geschid) ?></td>
         <td><?= $this->escapeHtml($mandant->name) ?></td>
         <td><?= $this->escapeHtml($mandant->langname) ?></td>
        <td>
            <a href="<?= $this->url('mandant', ['action' => 'show', 'id' => $mandant->id]) ?>">Show</a> 
            <a href="<?= $this->url('mandant', ['action' => 'edit', 'id' => $mandant->id]) ?>">Edit</a> 

        </td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

I'd to click the columnnames to sort the hole table. Like I click of name and the view ist sorted by name.

As you can see there is the rest of trying a bit. Is there anyway a possibility in the view or do I need a controlleraction? I really would like to do it in zend not with ajax or other.

How to do it properly?

****EDIT 1

I tried a bit further and created an action sortAction which returns a new Viewmodel:

```
        return new ViewModel([
        'mandants' => $this->mandantTable->sortMandant(0,0),
    ]);
```

This works of course but a also need a new viewscript and the given parameters to the called modelfunction pick the field which is sorted by. Second parameter gives asc or desc.

I really would appreciate to learn something about how to do it properly, like best practise.

Comment: There are many ways to solve your issue. One could be adding the column and the sort order (asc or desc) as get parameters to a route that executes an action by recognizing the get parameters. Another way could be sorting your tables with javascript. There are ready to use javascript scripts out there. Can you show us your whole controller action and the routing?

Comment: you can see the controller action in my post, you can see the routing here es well. The action is names sortAction, so there ist a viewscript. The Viewscript is give the mandants Object which comes from the sortMandant modelfunction. As you can see above, I don't want to use Javascript, I really would like to know what is best practise by using Zend and how to do it, an example would be nice also. So can you give me an Zend example?

Comment: why do I get a downvote? Is this a forum for questioning or just for selfcentered specialists? Thanks for explanation!!!!!

Comment: Don 't mind the downvote. Your question isn 't complete. You 're routing is only guessable by the url view helper you used in your view. It would be easier, wenn you point out all needed informations more exact. I 'll give you an example, how to deal with query parameters in your controller.

Comment: You may want the logic in your existing controller action rather than making a separate one for sorting. That way it'll use the view script you already have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code examples are written without testing. This should never be used in production. It 's just a push in the right direction.

**Query Parameters in the Controller**

Without touching the routing für your controller, query parameters are the easier way to get your issue solved.

```
YourController extends AbstractActionController
{
    protected $tableGateway;
    ...
    public function sortAction()
    {
         // contains the db field, which should the result sorted by or an empty string
         $sort = $this->params()->fromQuery('sort', '');

         // contains the sort direction the db query should ordered by (asc or desc)
         $direction = $this->params()->fromQuery('order', '');

         // executes sql query with the given parameters
         $result = $this->tableGateway->getSortedResult($sort, $direction);

         // return result to the view
         return new ViewModel([
             'result' => $result,
         ]);
    }
    ...
}
```

For safety reasons you should filter or validate your query parameters before you transfer it to your table gateway function.

**The Table Gateway with variable sort order**

The table gateway function `getSortedResult` should take two parameters `$sort` and `$direction`.

```
class YourTableGateway extends TableGateway
{
    ...
    public function getSortedResult(string $sort, string $direction) : ResultSet
    {
        $select = $this->getSql()->select();
        $select->columns([
            'column_a',
            'column_b',
            'column_c',
        ]);
        $select->order($sort . ' ' . $direction);

        $resultset = $this->selectWith($select);

        return $restulset;
    }
    ...
}
```

As you can see the given parameters are directly inserted into the order function of your select statement. *Please do not take this for production! Always check this parameters for fieldnames, that are in your table and directions ASC and DESC to avoid SQL injection!*

**The changes in your view**

You have to set a link in your table head with query parameters.

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th><a href="<?= $this->url('name', [ 'action' => 'show', 'id' => 1 ], [ 'query' => [ 'sort' => 'name', 'order' => 'ASC' ]]); ?>">Table Headline 1</a></th>
        <th><a href="<?= $this->url('name', [ 'action' => 'show', 'id' => 1 ], [ 'query' => [ 'sort' => 'gender', 'order' => 'ASC' ]]); ?>">Table Headline 2</a></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

The url view helper takes usually three parameters whereby the last parameters are optional. The first parameter is the name of your route. The second one defines route parameters defined in your route configuration. The third parameter is for optional parameters like query params. For your query params `sort` and `order` you have to note the `query` key, which has an array value of the column name, that should be ordered by and as second the direction, which should be sorted by.

Simple as pie, ha? ;)

**Conclusion**

A JavaScript solution would be more performant, because you don 't have to fire a request for every time you want to sort your result. That could be done by an initial request and the sorting would be done by the client. Anyway ... I think this is the JavaScript free Zend Framework only solution you wanted.